# Unwanted Duplicate Product Categories in WooCommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

On a WooCommerce site I am working on, there are duplicate pages for all of the subcategories.

ie:

https://www.examplesite.com/category/mens/tops/longsleeve/
and
https://www.examplesite.com/category/mens/longsleeve/
and
https://www.examplesite.com/category/longsleeve/

Those all lead to the same exact page with the same exact products.

I'm not sure where these URLs are being created. Is there a way I can disable the other 2 instances so I am left with only one working URL (https://www.examplesite.com/category/mens/tops/longsleeve/), to avoid duplicate content?

Thanks in advance!